# Are 4th Edition Shadowrun adventures compatible with 5th Edition?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun-sr4

I'm looking for some *Shadowrun* adventures to run for 5th Edition and I came across the *[Shadowrun Missions](http://www.shadowruntabletop.com/missions/)* living campaign. I found a few Season 4 missions I'm interested in (like [Back in Business](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product_info.php?products_id=87673)), but they seem like they are written for 4th Edition. Are these adventures compatible with 5th Edition? Do I need to make any changes?

**Related:** [What are the differences between Shadowrun 4th and 5th edition that I should know about?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/27101/7373), which is largely focused on character creation and how hacking and such work, but not adventures.

Comment: If you have an answer "focused on rules", what *else* do you need? The setting will be much the same.

Comment: @Adeptus I had meant gameplay, like how to hack. I'm mostly wondering, do I need to make adjustments to NPCs and such? Skill TNs?

Comment: @Ahriman I never knew there was an FAQ (I'm new to Shadowrun 5th). Would you consider creating an answer that points to it and includes the relevant quotes?

Comment: @Ahriman If you were talking about an FAQ for Shadowrun Missions, I should have clarified that I was looking at missions published under 4th Edition, like the 2011 [04-00: Back in Business](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product_info.php?products_id=87673). I'll edit the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly...

There have been some fairly significant changes between the two editions. Most notably, the Initiative mechanics are different, and the SR4 material won't have calculated any Limits for you. The mechanics of magic and the matrix are significantly different as well; even where named the same, a given numeric value doesn't have the same weight in both editions.

If you're comfortable with both editions and you have the right type of players, ones that won't nitpick specific numbers, it is possible to do "good-enough" conversions on the fly (much more so than SR3-to-SR4 would have been). That said, I would take the time to rebuild the key NPCs in advance and substitute SR5 template NPCs anywhere you can.